# Presence of non square elements in $GF(p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

I came across a problem which had a line of explanation as follows :

Let $a \in GF(p). a$ is a non square in $GF(p),~ p \neq 2 \implies \nexists~ b\in GF(p)~~|~~a =b^2 $.

But, is it really possible that $GF(p)$ contains a non square element? The non zero elements of $GF(p)$ form a group ( cyclic ) under multiplication and hence, the mapping $x \rightarrow x^2$ is a one-one, onto mapping.

Hence, $\forall~~x \in GF(p)~~x = y^2~~|~~ y \in GF(p)$.

And $0^2$ is of course $0$ in $GF(p)$.

Hence, can there really exist non square elements in $GF(p)$?

**EDIT:** I realize from Andreas's comment that the mapping $x \rightarrow x^2$ is not one-one. However, isn't this an example of a Frobenius mapping .

$\Psi:GF(p) \rightarrow GF(p)$ s.t. $a \rightarrow a^p$ where $p$ is a prime is considered a ring automorphism. Is there a contradiction?

Thank you for your help..

Comment: What makes you think that $x \mapsto x^2$ is one-to-one?  Consider $x=1$ and $x=-1$.

Comment: I think I made a mistake. But, my thinking was motivated from the Frobenius mapping $\Psi:GF(p) \rightarrow GF(p)$ s.t. $ a \rightarrow a^p$ where $p$ is a prime is considered a ring automorphism. Is there a contradiction?

Comment: @VHP The map $x \mapsto x^2$ is only a ring homomorphism if the ring has characteristic 2, so for $GF(p)$ with $p > 2$, you cannot conclude that $x \mapsto x^2$ is one-to-one or onto because it isn't a (ring) homomorphism of fields.

Comment: Oops yeah! Thank you for the comment.